# Unzip to location

Tags: shell, ssh, putty, zip

I am using unzip through putty and it works ok.
However, using the same command through a .NET C# SSH library ([Renci.SshNet](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/)) gives different results.

```
SshClient s = new SshClient("ssh_host", "ssh_port", "ssh_username", "ssh_password");
SshCommand c = s.RunCommand("unzip -o \"/home/parent/child/1.zip\ 1.txt"")
```

This same command through putty, extracts it in 'child', using this, the 1.txt ends up in 'parent'. The return result of the Sshcommand is the same as Putty's return :

```
Archive:  /home/parent/child/1.zip
extracting: 1.txt
```

Why is it extracting one level up? The only difference i can see is that i used cd to position myself to the directory (in Putty).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or use unzip's -d option to specify the directory to which to extract files.

```
SshCommand c = s.RunCommand("unzip -d /home/parent/child -o \"/home/parent/child/1.zip\ 1.txt"")
```

Comment: +1 Any other advantages to using this?

Answer (score 1):

Got it.

```
SshCommand c = s.RunCommand("cd /home/parent/child/ && unzip -o 1.zip 1.txt"))
```

Using this syntax i position my self to the folder and do the unzip.